# Python Parsing xml files

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
<goal>
<value>
    <comment>n</comment>
    <stats>
        <goals>1</goals>
        <shoton>1</shoton>
    </stats>
    <event_incident_typefk>406</event_incident_typefk>
    <elapsed>22</elapsed>
    <player2>38807</player2>
    <subtype>header</subtype>
    <player1>37799</player1>
    <sortorder>5</sortorder>
    <team>10261</team>
    <id>378998</id><n>295</n>
    <type>goal</type>
    <goal_type>n</goal_type>
</value>
<value>
    <comment>n</comment>
    <stats>
        <goals>1</goals>
        <shoton>1</shoton>
    </stats>
    <event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk>
    <elapsed>24</elapsed>
    <player2>24154</player2>
    <subtype>shot</subtype>
    <player1>24148</player1>
    <sortorder>4</sortorder>
    <team>10260</team>
    <id>379019</id><n>298</n>
    <type>goal</type>
    <goal_type>n</goal_type>
</value>
```

```
def extract_goal_type(data):
    #print(data)
    if data :
        root = ET.fromstring(data)
        tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for c in root.getchildren():
            return c.findtext('subtype')
```

the problem is that the function is only returning the first subset and l can't seem to get the other ... l also have XML files which have up to 6 children. Please help on how l can parse this to get everything which is in XML.... Thank you

```
expected out
```

1. header
2. shot

Comment: The XML is invalid. It's missing the closing `</goal>`. You cannot parse it

Comment: Besides that you have to collect all findings in a list and return the list in the end, instead of returning the first one you find.

Answer (score 0):

You are retuning from the `for` loop, you have to travers for all element then return data.

```
def extract_goal_type(data):
    #print(data)
    ret_data = []
    if data :
        root = ET.fromstring(data)
        tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for c in root.getchildren():
            ret_data.append(c.findtext('subtype'))
    return ret_data
```

*Note: This will only work if you have valid XML*

Comment: Thank you so much but just one question ... how can l get the answers back into separate tabs on a table?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask in seperate thread. People can give better answer if you give all details